# Where to load View Parser service in Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am not understanding loading the parser service in Codeigniter 4, Please tell me how to load and where to load it, and how can i use it in View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the parser inside of the controller method that you want to use it in e.g. inside of index() method of Home controller. You may load it using `$parser = \Config\Services::parser();` or `$parser = service('parser');`.

Rendering a view can be done by echoing as follows:

```php
echo $parser->setData($data)->render($view);
```

wherein $data can be something like `['blog_title' => 'My Blog Title', 'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Heading'];` and $view is the address of your view file inside of /Views directory.

This will then replace any 'substitutions' in view file such as `<h1>{blog_title}</h1>` with your data. You can read more about the specifics of substitutions in docs.

**Note:** Using the Parser, your view templates are processed only by the Parser itself, and not like a conventional view PHP script. PHP code in such a script is ignored by the parser, and only substitutions are performed.

Comment: Thank you it works for me.
echo $parser->setData($data)->render('view_filename');